# django rest framework use different create methods in model manager

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Happy new years everyone, I've implemented a different create method on my model manager, and am trying to find a way to override my django rest serializer to use the new method? is this possible?

```
class PrivateUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    """
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_token')
    convert_user = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-convert')
    set_password = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-set-password')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'gender', 'country',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'groups', 'token', 'convert_user', 'set_password')
```

this is how my serializer looks like, and I want to use create_user method in my model manager instead of the usual save. Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into overriding the `restore_object` method, see [here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#declaring-serializers).